# Manipulate call in progress with only keypress with Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to manipulate (play menu, put on hold, transfer etc) call in progress by having the caller or called party press a special key such as #.

For example, I would like to allow a called party to be able to transfer a call from their cell phone by just pressing the # key.

When the pound key is pressed, I could play a menu such as "What do you want to do with this call?" "Press 1 to place on hold, 2 to transfer, 3 to send to voicemail" etc.

I know I can do this all day long if the user has a web interface or possibly even having the user text something but.. I don't want the user to be required to send a text message or have a web interface handy.

Thanks in advance for any assistance here.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found the very feature you mentioned several hours later but forgot to update my post. Thanks for the additional info and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do that yes. There is a simplified version of your request explained in these two blog posts handling transferring calls, depending on your language of choice:

- [Warm Phone Call Transfers with Python, Flask and Twilio Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/warm-phone-call-transfers-with-python-flask-and-twilio-voice.html)
- [How to Warm Transfer a Call with Java and Twilio Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/how-to-warm-transfer-a-call-with-java-and-twilio-voice.html)

Essentially, the idea is that you use a conference call that allows one party to hang up on the call using the * key. You do this by setting the [`hangupOnStar` property on the `<Dial>` verb to true](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#examples-6).

When hanging up with the * you can then give the call admin a list of options, such as transfer, using the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb which can then be applied to the call.

I recommend reading through one of those posts for all the details.